# Comma separated values from SQL, getting distinct values and their count

Tags: c#, linq

I have this issue where i have a `column` in `SQL table`. the values are in `comma separated` format.

ex:

```
 1)   facebook,google,just giving, news letter, in-store
 2)   facebook,google,just giving
 3)   just giving
 4)   facebook
 5)   google
 6)   in-store,email
 7)   email,facebook
```

Now i want to query that table and get this values in a list where list contains distinct values and their count.

ex:

```
1) facebook - 10 
2) email - 20
3) in-store -5
and so on....
```

is there anyway to achieve this using LINQ?

NOTE: i can work on LINQ operators on LIST variable because my datasource which is '`entries'` does not support LINQ( built in .NET 2.0)

```
        var results = new List<string>();
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var entry in entries.Cast<MWCompetitionsEntry>().Where(entry => entry.HowFound != null))
        {
              builder.Append(entry.HowFound).Append(",");
        }

        results.Add(builder.ToString());
```

## RESULTS i am getting

```
facebook,email,in-store,google,in-store,newsletter,facebook,email,facebok
```

## EDITS:

Now, I can work on `results` variable. i dont know how to get the unique values from that variable and their count.

please help

## ANSWER

```
var values = new List<string>();
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            var howFoundValues = new List<string>{"Email", "Facebook", "Twitter", "Leaflet", "Just Giving", "In-Store", "Other"};

            foreach (var entry in entries.Cast<MWCompetitionsEntry>().Where(entry => entry.HowFound != null))
            {
                  builder.Append(entry.HowFound).Append(",");
            }

            values.Add(builder.ToString());
            var result1 = values.SelectMany(l => l.Split(','))
                  .Where(howFoundValues.Contains) //will disregard any other items
                  .GroupBy(e => e)
                  .Select(e => String.Format("{0} - {1}",e.Key, e.Count()))
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var groupedResults = results.SelectMany(v => v.Split(','))
                        .GroupBy(n => n)
                        .Select((item, index) => 
                                 new {
                                    name = String.Format("{0}) {1}", index+1, item.Key),
                                    count = item.Count()
                                 })
                        .ToList();
```

1. You need to group elements by name.
2. In LINQ to Objects .Select() operator can second paramater in lambda as index, that can help you to attach numeration.

Comment: my issue is my datasouurce class was build in .NET 2.0 and it does not support any linq operators so i have to use foreach and append the string in some variable. BUT it gives me error on 'count = n.Count()' i dont know why... it says can not resolve symbol Count()

Comment: But you are using SelectMany(), that is LINQ operator, I had mistakes in my code, just updated it.

Comment: yes.. but i can operate on LIST not on my datasource.. like entries.SelectMany ...

Comment: OK i ma getting the result as '1) System.Linq.Lookup`2+Grouping[System.String,System.String]'

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your last question, could you please specify it?

Comment: i am getting result in this format { name = "8) System.Linq.Lookup`2+Grouping[System.String,System.String]", count = 12 }

Comment: Sorry, I missed to add .Key to item. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
var result = from word in entries.SelectMany(e => e.HowFound.Split(','))
             group word by word into gr
             select new {Entry = gr.Key, Count = gr.Count()};
```

grouping instead of distinct allows you to get the count.

Comment: my issue is my datasouurce class was build in .NET 2.0 and it does not support any linq operators so i have to use foreach and append the string in some variable.

Comment: @patel.milanb You tagged your question with `linq` so so get linq results.

Comment: Not only tagged, the question specifically says: `how can i achieve this in LINQ.`

Comment: I can operate linq on LIST variable but not on my data source like entries.SelectMany ... i have to get all the values using foreach and create one string and then split it by ',' and then get the distinct values.

Comment: @patel.milanb Just read the values into a list of string, so you have a list variable like the one in my answer

Comment: can you edit your answer to work on results variable as per my edit please

Answer (score 1):

```
var entries = new List<string>{"facebook,google,just giving, news letter, in-store",
 "facebook,google,just giving",
 "just giving", 
 "facebook",
 "google",
 "in-store,email",
 "email,facebook"};

var result = entries
.SelectMany (e => e.Split(','))
.GroupBy (e => e).Select (g => string.Format("{0} - {1}", g.Count (), g.Key));

result.Dump();
```

results in

```
4 - facebook 
3 - google 
3 - just giving 
1 -  news letter 
1 -  in-store 
1 - in-store 
2 - email
```

It's splitting yout entries first, then grouping by different strings.

If your data contains leading and/or trailing spaces like they do in your example, consider using `.GroupBy(e => e.Trim())`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        Dictionary<string, int> valuesAndCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (var entry in entries) // entries is a collection of records from table
        {
            string[] values = entry.Split(',');
            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                if (!valuesAndCount.ContainsKey(value))
                {
                    valuesAndCount.Add(value, 0);
                }
                valuesAndCount[value] = valuesAndCount[value] + 1;
            }
        }


        //Then you'llhave your distinct values and thei count
        foreach (var key in valuesAndCount.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",key, valuesAndCount[key]);
        }
```

Then the dictionary should contain your distinct values and their count

LINQ VERSION

```
        IEnumerable<string> strings = entries
            .ToList()
            .SelectMany(e => e.Split(','))
            .GroupBy(v => v)
            .Select(str => string.Format("{0} {1}", str.Count(), str.Key));


        foreach (var p in strings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p);
        }
```

Comment: i am able to see the values and their count using this method... BUT is there any way to use LINQ in this